# Given projection PP is weak-star to weak-star continuous

Tags: soft-question, banach-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space, and $P$ be a projection of $X^*$ such that $\Vert P \Vert\leq 1$ and $\ker(P)$, ${\bf ran}(1-p)$ are weak-star closed. Show that $P$
is weak-star to weak-star continuous.

I welcome if any body give hints or any ideas to prove it.

Comment: Why the soft-question tag? Is this an exercise?

Comment: @ Jochen, I feel it should be simple proof which I am not getting.

Comment: $P$ is clearly weak$^*$ continuous on bounded sets.  If you want to avoid using the full force of the Krein-Smulian Theorem, use the simple lemma Robert Whitlley proved in  http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1986-097-02/S0002-9939-1986-0835903-X/S0002-9939-1986-0835903-X.pdf  to show that $P^*$ maps $X$ back into $X$.

Comment: R. Whitley, The Krein-Smulian Theorem, PAMS 97 (1986), 376-377.

Comment: The "soft-question" tag is not meant for _easy questions_,  but for questions that do not necessarily have precise interpretations or precise answers